# "Input string was not in a correct format" on Parse procedure

Tags: c#, indexing

I'm not too experienced in this area of programming and I am stuck on the following error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

This appears on the following line of my code:

```
decimal amount = decimal.Parse(entry.Split('$')[0]);
```

I'm not too sure on how to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Documents\\Streamtip\\tip-top.txt", String.Empty);

Dictionary<string, decimal> names = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
sR = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Documents\\Streamtip\\tip-list-recent.txt");
while (!sR.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sR.ReadLine();
    var entries = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        decimal amount = decimal.Parse(entry.Split('$')[0]);
        string nameSplit = entry.Split('.', ':')[1].Trim();

        if (names.ContainsKey(nameSplit))
        {
            names[nameSplit] += amount;
            Console.WriteLine("Hoozah!");
        }
        else
        {
            names.Add(nameSplit, amount);
            Console.WriteLine("Failure");
        }
    }

} sR.Close();
```

EDIT
Inputted data

`1. Jim: $22.00, 2. Jim: $2100.00, 3. Jim: $6.00, 4. Jim: $32.00, 5. Jim: $2.00,`

Comment: What's the value in `entry`? Presumably it's some kind of dollar amount - e.g. `$9.99`?

Comment: Representative examples of some lines from `tip-list-recent.txt` would be helpful.  You're getting that error because the extracted value is not a number.

Comment: That's correct, I was give some of this code by a fellow SO member who attempted to help me. However, this error began to occur.

Comment: BTW, I'm a big fan of `Console.WriteLine("Hoozah!")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think you want `entry.Split('$')[1]` not `entry.Split('$')[0]` since the dollar value is after the dollar sign.

In general, you should use [`decimal.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check for bad inputs, or alternatively catch the various exceptions from [`decimal.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
try
{
    decimal amount = decimal.Parse(entry.Split('$')[1]);
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
    // handle the error.
}
```

For instance:

```
       foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            try
            {
                var tokens = entry.Split('$');
                decimal amount;
                if (tokens.Length > 1)
                    amount = decimal.Parse(tokens[1]);
                else
                    throw new FormatException("invalid entry");

                string nameSplit = entry.Split('.', ':')[1].Trim();

                if (names.ContainsKey(nameSplit))
                {
                    names[nameSplit] += amount;
                    Console.WriteLine("Hoozah!");
                }
                else
                {
                    names.Add(nameSplit, amount);
                    Console.WriteLine("Failure");
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Format exception for entry \"{0}\"", entry));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} for entry \"{1}\"", ex.GetType().Name, entry));
            }
        }
```

**Update**

Then, if you need to output the total amount per name, at the end of the routine you can do:

```
    foreach (var pair in names)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1:C2}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
```

Comment: I have no idea on the use of `parse`. Hence I am finding this extremely difficult. Also, it may be, I'll have a look @DStanley

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse - I don't get an index out of range error with the Inputted data line you provided.  Can you show the line that gives the problem?

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse the above code works correctly if the value of `line` is `1. Jim: $22.00, 2. Jim: $2100.00, 3. Jim: $6.00, 4. Jim: $32.00, 5. Jim: $2.00,`. See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ct2pHR, not sure why you get an out of index range error.

Comment: It worked! The only problem now is that I'd like to replace "Hoozah" with the amount that has been added up for a person. For example, if it were `Jay: $200.00, Phil: $300, Jay: $20.00`. I'd then like 200 and 20 to be added and printed. Is that what this code is doing?

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse - it certainly is correctly adding the values for the specified input lines.  See update for how to print them.

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming that `entry.Split('$')[0]` is a numeric value when it is not.  When reading user input, you should use `TryParse()` instead so you can trap errors.

Edit: dbc is right, but you should still do this and not assume your input file is perfect.

```
decimal amount = 0;

if (decimal.TryParse(entry.Split('$')[0], out amount))
{
    string nameSplit = entry.Split('.', ':')[1].Trim();

    if (names.ContainsKey(nameSplit))
    {
        names[nameSplit] += amount;
        Console.WriteLine("Hoozah!");
    }
    else
    {
        names.Add(nameSplit, amount);
        Console.WriteLine("Failure");
    }
}
else
{
    // the input file has an invalid line, do something about it
}
```

Comment: But how would entry be created? Previously I had `(var entry in entries)`

Comment: This goes inside your `foreach`.

Comment: I see! I'll test the program when I get home tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`decimal.Parse` has an overload that accepts a `NumberStyle`, and you can choose `Currency`. This avoids having to use `split` and splitting the string from the `$`.

```
decimal amount = decimal.Parse(entry, NumberStyles.Currency);
```